# psyco2.error.syntax error:syntax error at the end of input )

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

I'm trying to run a `sql` query in python. It did work in `pgadmin`, but python reported the syntax error.

```py
cur_str.execute("select b2.linestring,b2.id,ST_Length(ST_Intersection(ST_Transform(ST_MakeValid(b2.linestring),28992),ST_Transform(ST
_MakeValid(b1.geom), 28992))) from public.ways b2, public.pc4_2017 b1 where ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(ST_MakeValid(b2.linestring),28992)
,ST_Transform(ST_MakeValid(b1.geom),28992)",([pc4]))
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ...linestring),28992),ST_Transform(ST_MakeValid(b1.geom),28992)
                                                                       ^
```

Can I get some help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use triple quotes to make a multiline string in Python:

```
cur_str.execute("""
    select 
        b2.linestring,
        b2.id,
        ST_Length(ST_Intersection(ST_Transform(ST_MakeValid(b2.linestring),28992), ST_Transform(ST_MakeValid(b1.geom), 28992)))
    from 
        public.ways b2, 
        public.pc4_2017 b1 
    where 
        ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(ST_MakeValid(b2.linestring),28992),ST_Transform(ST_MakeValid(b1.geom),28992))
    """, ([pc4]))
```